# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que dos tablas llamadas historial y datos muestren los resultados de reservaciones cancelados?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, crystal-reports

estoy trabajando con un store procedure para que me de la reservaciones canceladas de un proyecto de la escuela, hasta el momento tengo esta consulta que maneja un parametro de historial pero ya no lo quiero usar, quiero que muestre todas las cancelaciones de las dos tablas tratando de optimizarlo lo más que pueda.

```
@FECHAINI AS DATETIME,
    @FECHAFIN AS DATETIME,
    @USUARIO AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @HISTORIAL AS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @QUERY AS VARCHAR(MAX)
        
        SET @QUERY = 'SELECT
        CASE WHEN (garantiada = ''S'') THEN ''G'' ELSE '''' END AS garantiada,
        case when STATUSDA = ''R'' then ''Reserva-Conf'' when STATUSDA = ''E'' then ''Reserva-XConf'' when STATUSDA = ''L'' then ''Reserva-L.Espera'' when STATUSDA = ''C'' then ''Cancelada'' when STATUSDA = ''X'' then ''Cancelada(L,E)'' when STATUSDA = ''O'' then ''Check-In'' when STATUSDA = ''B'' then ''Bloqueada'' when STATUSDA = ''G'' then ''Grupos'' when STATUSDA = ''D'' then ''Check-out'' when STATUSDA = ''F'' then ''Check-Out Folio'' else STATUSDA end as STATUSDA,
        NUMRESDA,NOMBREDA,NUMPERDA, TARIFADA,
        SUBSTRING(cveestda1,2,LEN(cveestda1)) as cveestda1, 
        NUMCUADA, FHAENTDA, FHASALDA,
        SUBSTRING(cveestda14,2,LEN(cveestda14)) as pqte, 
        SUBSTRING(cveestda2,2,LEN(cveestda2)) as age, 
        SUBSTRING(cveestda4,2,LEN(cveestda4)) as seg, 
        SUBSTRING(cveestda5,2,LEN(cveestda5)) as pg, 
        SUBSTRING(cveestda6,2,LEN(cveestda6)) as cia, 
        NUMCANDA, DEPOSIDA,
        DATEDIFF(DAY,FhaEntda,FhaSalda) as Noches,
        FECHRESDA,PASEDA
        FROM '
        IF (@HISTORIAL = 'S')
            SET @QUERY += 'historial'
        IF (@HISTORIAL = 'N')
            SET @QUERY += 'datos'

        SET @QUERY += ' WHERE FECHRESDA BETWEEN '''+ CAST(@FECHAINI AS VARCHAR(MAX))+''' AND '''+CAST(@FECHAFIN AS VARCHAR(MAX))+''' '

        IF (@USUARIO <> '')
            SET @QUERY += 'and STATUSDA = ''C'' and PASEDA = '''+ @USUARIO +''' ORDER BY nombreda'
        ELSE
            SET @QUERY += 'and STATUSDA = ''C'' ORDER BY nombreda'

        PRINT(@QUERY)
    EXEC (@QUERY)
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        SELECT  ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRORMESSAGE;  
    END CATCH
END
```

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento he estado haciendo modificaciones pero no me sale, ya use union all y solo el union para la tablas pero no funciona, cabe mencionar que este SP lo estoy usando para un reporte en crystal reports.

Comment: Me llama mucho la atención que para un valor uses dos veces la comilla simple, ejemplo: ''S''. Lo siguiente que me sorprende es que castees una fecha a Varchar y le asignes un MAX como si una fecha tuviera mil caracteres. Sin mencionar que en tu between usas tres comillas simples '''. De todas formas, si lo que quieres es mostrar todas, simplemente quita los if de tu from

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo la doble comilla sencilla es porque está dentro de una cadena de caracteres. Pero el verdadero problema es el concatenar valores a la consulta porque eso abre la posibilidad a inyección SQL.

Comment: ¿Cómo sería una buena practica de hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Hay varios detalles con tu consulta. Para empezar, el uso de código dinámico sería poco recomendable en este caso. Aun cuando quisieras usarlo, lo ideal es usar consultas parametrizadas en vez de concatenar valores. Para poder usar consultas parametrizadas, usamos el procedimiento especial `sp_executesql`.

También es importante limitar el tamaño de las variables y parámetros para optimizar el uso de memoria y prevenir ataques.

Dejo un ejemplo de como haría la consulta. Dejé el parámetro @Historial, pero agregué la opción de 'ambas' aunque puedes quitarlo por completo. También cambié la función para eliminar el primer caracter de las claves. Dejé un comentario sobre la expresión de `STATUSDA`. Un último detalle es que el manejo de errores parece ineficiente y puede generar otro error al obtener el resultado del procedimiento con una estructura totalmente distinta a la ejecución normal.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DatosCancelados
    @FECHAINI  AS DATETIME,
    @FECHAFIN  AS DATETIME,
    @USUARIO   AS VARCHAR(128),
    @HISTORIAL AS CHAR(1)
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRY
    WITH cteDatos AS(
        SELECT 
            garantiada AS garantiada,
            STATUSDA   AS STATUSDA  ,
            NUMRESDA   AS NUMRESDA  ,
            NOMBREDA   AS NOMBREDA  ,
            NUMPERDA   AS NUMPERDA  , 
            TARIFADA   AS TARIFADA  ,
            cveestda1  AS cveestda1 ,
            NUMCUADA   AS NUMCUADA  , 
            FHAENTDA   AS FHAENTDA  , 
            FHASALDA   AS FHASALDA  ,
            cveestda14 AS cveestda14,
            cveestda2  AS cveestda2 ,
            cveestda4  AS cveestda4 ,
            cveestda5  AS cveestda5 ,
            cveestda6  AS cveestda6 ,
            NUMCANDA   AS NUMCANDA  , 
            DEPOSIDA   AS DEPOSIDA  ,
            FhaEntda   AS FhaEntda  ,
            FhaSalda   AS FhaSalda  ,
            FECHRESDA  AS FECHRESDA ,
            PASEDA     AS PASEDA
        FROM datos
        WHERE @HISTORIAL IN( 'N', 'A')
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            garantiada AS garantiada,
            STATUSDA   AS STATUSDA,
            NUMRESDA   AS NUMRESDA  ,
            NOMBREDA   AS NOMBREDA  ,
            NUMPERDA   AS NUMPERDA  , 
            TARIFADA   AS TARIFADA  ,
            cveestda1  AS cveestda1 ,
            NUMCUADA   AS NUMCUADA  , 
            FHAENTDA   AS FHAENTDA  , 
            FHASALDA   AS FHASALDA  ,
            cveestda14 AS cveestda14,
            cveestda2  AS cveestda2 ,
            cveestda4  AS cveestda4 ,
            cveestda5  AS cveestda5 ,
            cveestda6  AS cveestda6 ,
            NUMCANDA   AS NUMCANDA  , 
            DEPOSIDA   AS DEPOSIDA  ,
            FhaEntda   AS FhaEntda  ,
            FhaSalda   AS FhaSalda  ,
            FECHRESDA  AS FECHRESDA ,
            PASEDA     AS PASEDA
        FROM historial
        WHERE @HISTORIAL IN( 'S', 'A')
    )

    SELECT
        CASE WHEN (garantiada = 'S') THEN 'G' ELSE '' END AS garantiada,
        --Esta expresión está de más si STATUSDA siempre será 'C'
        CASE WHEN STATUSDA = 'R' THEN 'Reserva-Conf' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'E' THEN 'Reserva-XConf' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'L' THEN 'Reserva-L.Espera' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'C' THEN 'Cancelada' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'X' THEN 'Cancelada(L,E)' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'O' THEN 'Check-In' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'B' THEN 'Bloqueada' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'G' THEN 'Grupos' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'D' THEN 'Check-out' 
             WHEN STATUSDA = 'F' THEN 'Check-Out Folio' 
            ELSE STATUSDA END AS STATUSDA,
        NUMRESDA,
        NOMBREDA,
        NUMPERDA, 
        TARIFADA,
        STUFF( cveestda1, 1, 1, '') as cveestda1, 
        NUMCUADA, FHAENTDA, FHASALDA,
        STUFF( cveestda14, 1, 1, '') as pqte, 
        STUFF( cveestda2 , 1, 1, '') as age, 
        STUFF( cveestda4 , 1, 1, '') as seg, 
        STUFF( cveestda5 , 1, 1, '') as pg, 
        STUFF( cveestda6 , 1, 1, '') as cia, 
        NUMCANDA, 
        DEPOSIDA,
        DATEDIFF(DAY,FhaEntda,FhaSalda) as Noches,
        FECHRESDA,
        PASEDA
    FROM cteDatos
    WHERE FECHRESDA BETWEEN @FECHAINI AND @FECHAFIN 
    AND   STATUSDA = 'C' 
    AND   (PASEDA = @USUARIO OR @USUARIO IS NULL OR @USUARIO = '') 
    ORDER BY nombreda;

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT  ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ERRORMESSAGE;  
END CATCH
```